# Confirm Delete on Javascript Remove Event

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-events

I'm using a Javascript call to dynamically remove a field from a form.  My problem is that the action happens very quickly, and it's not reversible.  So I'd like to add the standard Rails delete confirmation, but I can't figure out how to make it work.  Basically, I want to add this ... :confirm => ‘Are you sure?’

Here's the line of Javascript responsible for removing the field:

`<%= link_to_function “Remove”, ”$(this).up(’.task’).remove()” %>`

This is from a standard implementation of the Ryan Bates multi-model form technique from Advanced Rails Recipes.

I can provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the `:confirm` option is available on `link_to_function` is it?

Try adding it yourself:

```
<%= link_to_function "Remove",
        "if(confirm('Are you sure?')) $(this).up('.task').remove()" %>
```